# Regex: Same number of a's at back and front

Tags: regex

The regex I'm trying to find is of the form `a^k s a^k`, `k >= 1`, where s is an arbitrary string over the alphabet `{a,b}`. For example `aaaabbbaaa` is in the language because it can be expressed as `a^3 abbb a^3`.

EDIT: With the limitation that you can only use concatenation (ab), union (a|b), star (a*) and plus (a+).
How do I write a regex for this?

EDIT:
I was right, `(a(a|b)*a)+` does capture this.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need `+`, just `a(a|b)*a`, since your language is essentially `a s a`. If `s` were for example `{b,c}` the language `a^k s a^k` would be context-sensitive and thus unmatchable by strict regular expressions, although modern regex engines could match it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `a+(a|b)*a+`? That would be one or more `a`'s, followed by `a` or `b` zero or more times, followed by `a` one or more times? That way, at least `a^1` will be at the front and back so every string will be in your language and since `+` is one or more times, it can go `a^1` to `a^infinity`.
If s must be at least length one, change the `*` to a `+`.

EDIT: Yours will work although you could take the plus sign out at the end and still have it working.

Comment: With (a(a|b)*a)+ I think this means s has to be repeated in a certain pattern k times. I don't see how I can capture aaaabbbaaa, because s is abbb in this case and how can I make (a(a|b)*a)^3 capture this? Correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: I think you figured it out based on your edit but you would only need to apply your pattern once: Your first a will get the first a. a|b will get all of the letters till the last a and then your last a will match the last a.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
^(a+)[ab]+\1$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aF6qF2/1)

Comment: How do I write the regex with just the operators: Union (a|b), Concatenation (ab), Plus (a+) and Star (a*)?

Comment: @solistice: you didn't mention any kind of limitation.